# Can you clean report folder in Nightwatch.js before each run?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

If I have screenshots enabled, they are saved when I run a test. When I rerun the test, the old screenshots are still visible. This will cause a problem the bigger the scripts get and the more screenshots that might be saved.

Coming from Protractor, the report folder was always wiped before a test. Is there a way to achieve this with Nightwatch?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with .sh file , for example: let create exec.sh

```
rm -rf "your report directory"
nightwatch -c ./Nighwatch.js
```

Then execute exec.sh by : `./exec.sh`

OR

you can user this package ,https://github.com/jls/nightwatch-html-reporter It will generate reports in html files

Comment: I currently have that plugin and it recreates the report just fine. Only problem is that when new tests are ran the screenshots are not replaced. So, it looks like manually is the only way of doing this? It's not automatic like in protractor?

Answer (score 0):

First, install rimraf and add a new script:

```
"clean":"rimraf dist logs screenshots test_output"
```

you can run this to delete the reports-related files

> npm run clean

or you can modify your test scripts like:

```
"test": "npm run clean && nightwatch"
```